# Limit question concerning the ratio of two functions.

Tags: limits, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two continuous functions such that:

- $f(a) = g(a) = 0$.
- In the limit as $x \to a$, $f'(x)/g'(x) \to 1$.  (By L'Hôpital's rule, this of course implies that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)/g(x) = 1$.)
- $f'(x) > g'(x)$ for all $x > a$.

Is it then true that $f(x)/g(x) > 1$ for all $x > a$?  If not, what would be sufficient additional conditions that this is true?  I feel like there should be a simple proof of this fact, but I've been working in circles on this problem and I can't quite put my finger on it.

(For the record, the specific problem that I'm interested in is $a = 1$, $f(x) = x^\gamma - 1$, and $g(x) = \gamma(x - 1)$, with $\gamma$ any real number strictly greater than 1.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$$for some $c$ between $a$ and $x$, by [Cauchy's mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy%27s_mean_value_theorem). So…

Note that my answer assumes that you always have $g'(x)\neq0$.

Comment: Does this mean that the condition that $\lim_{x \to a} f'(x)/g'(x) = 1$ is unnecessary?  Or does it follow somehow from the first and last conditions?

Comment: I've just added to my answer that I've used Cauchy's mean value theorem. And I don't think that I've used the hypothesis that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=1$.

Comment: You need $g'(x)$ not to have zeros in some $(a,a+\varepsilon]$, otherwise Cauchy can't be used. This may or may not be consistent with $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=1$, depending on interpretation ($g'$ could be frequently zero, but we might implicitly assume that $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ is the "continuously extended" $\frac{f'}{g'}$ if such an extension exists).

Comment: @Gae.S. You are right. I shall edit my answer.